# Get next closest time from a table based on selected hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, time, html-table

I have a long table with columns of schedule data that I'm loading via a form with jQuery `load()`. I have access to these html pages with the table data and can add classes/data attributes etc.

My form has `select` fields for hours and minutes (defaulting to the current time) and I'm trying to get the next closest time plus the four after that.

The time data in my tables are all formatted as `<td>H:MM</td>`.

Ideally with jQuery, I was wondering how I can strip the table data of everything but those times. Alternatively, since I can reformat this data would I be making my life easier to format it a certain way?

**Things I've tried** - I am admittedly a novice at js so these things may seem silly:

- Reading the first character of each cell and comparing it to the
  selected hour. This is obviously a problem with 10, 11, 12 and is
  really intensive (this is a mobile site)
- Using a single time `select` field thenCreating an Array of each
  column to compare with the selected time. Couldn't get this working
  and also creates an issue with having to use a single select for
  every time.

Basically looking for a little guidance on how to get this working short of, or maybe including, copying all the html tables into JSON format...

Comment: I would suggest doing the filtering on the server and returning the data using json, in sorted order, starting with the closest to the submitted time. I assume you are already manipulating some sort of `datetime` object on the server so it is likely the most appropriate place for the filtering/sorting logic

Comment: It's actually straight up .html files filled with tables. Not my choice, but what I have to work with.

Comment: i really can't understand your question... provide the code

Comment: @Grillz Ok, still doable. Are the table rows sorted by time? i.e. earliest to latest?

Comment: They are. nrabinowitz hit it exactly. I kind of awed in fact :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this was an interesting question, so I put together a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/T4ng8/

The basic steps here are:

1. Parse the time data ahead of time and store using `.data()`. To facilitate comparison, I'm suggesting storing the time data as a float, using `parseFloat(hh + '.' + mm)`.
2. In your change handler, use a loop to go through the cells in sequence, stopping when you find the index of the cell with a `time` value higher than your selected time. Decrement the index, since you've gone one step too far
3. Use `.toggle(i >= index && i < index+4)` in an `.each()` loop to hide and show the appropriate rows.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I can"t tell you how much I appreciate this.

Answer (score 2):

May as well post http://jsbin.com/ozebos/16/edit, though I was beaten to it :)

Basic mode of operation is similar to @nrabinowitz

1. On load, parse the time strings in some way and add to `data` on each row
2. On filter (i.e. user manipulates a form), the chosen time is parsed in the same way. The rows are filtered on `row.data('time') >= chosen_time`
3. The resulting array of elements limited to 5 (closest time plus four as OP requested) using `.slice(0, 5)`
4. All rows are hidden, these rows are displayed.

Some assumptions have been made, so this code serves only as a pointer to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Still helpful for me to learn for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it on client side. This is just an outline, but should give you an idea.

```
// Create a sorted array of times from the table
var times = []
$('#mytable td').each(function(cell) {
  times.push(cell.innerHTML);
});
times.sort();

// Those times are strings, and they can be compared, e.g. '16.30' > '12.30' returns true. 
var currentTime = '12:30' // you probably need to read this from your select
var i = 0;
while (times[i] < currentTime || i=times.length) {
  i++;
}

var closestTime = times[i];
var closestTimes = times.slice(i, i+4);
```

If you want to access not the times, but actually the cells containing the times, you can find them like this:

```
$('#mytable td').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() in closestTimes) {
    // do something to that cell
  }
})
```